# How do i search XML when / is in it? C#? 

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I get this error with the code

```
var ff = from files in doc.Descendants("blah/Files") select files;
```

The error is

```
The '/' character, hexadecimal value 0x2F, cannot be included in a name.
```

In `<Files>` there are

```
<File id="f8" name="/usr/include/_G_config.h"/>
```

Now i cant change the XML and i need to access everything in it. How do i do that in C#?

Comment: What is `blah`? Why won't `doc.Descendants("Files")` work?

Comment: Why was this down voted? I think it is a valid enough question with enough info.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The parameter to [Descendants](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb353813.aspx) must be an [XName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xname.aspx) (which can be implicitly converted from a string), which represents an element or attribute name.  These can not contain slashes.  Depending on the full XML, you may just be able to use:

```
doc.Descendants("Files")
```

or you may need to add code.

Answer (score 2):

You are trying it out like you would an XPath but it expects an XName and an XName cannot have a "/" in it

Instead you can directly do something like this:

```
var ff = from file in doc.Descendants("file") select file;
```